# Reading data from a text file, then getting the average

Tags: input, output, average

I'm very new to programming and I seem to have ran into a wall. I'm trying to write a simple code that reads scores from different Bowlers and then finding the average for each Bowler. My code seems to read the first line of scores and then stops. Any advice? Here's what I have

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <vector>

using namespace std;



int main ()
{


    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    double score1, score2, score3;
    double average;

    string firstname;
    string lastname;  

    inFile.open ("scores.txt");
    outFile.open ("scoreavg.out");

    ifstream ("scores.txt");
    string content;

    while (inFile >> content)
    {
        cout << content << ' ';



    inFile >> firstname >> lastname ;
    outFile << "Bowler name: " <<firstname << " " << lastname << endl;

    inFile >> score1 >> score2 >> score3;
    outFile << "scores: " << setw(4) << score1 << setw(4) << score2 << setw(4)<< score3 << endl;

    average = (score1 + score2 + score3)/3;

    outFile << "Average score: " << setw(4) << average<< endl;

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();

    return 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to add a language-specific tag to your post. Is it `c++`?

Comment: `return 0;` exists your function. Take it out from your while loop.

Comment: oh I'm sorry Imissed that... it's C++

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the `return 0;` statement is inside the `while` loop.

You want your loop to do some reading and averaging for each record in the input.  Once that's done, you then cleanup by closing the files. So the loop ends after the record is processed and before the cleanup.

Move the brace from after the `return` to before the first `close`.